# Styling links in a web app

Tags: html, css, web-applications, user-interface, user-experience

I am building a web app that will have a large number of clickable elements. The problem is if I style this with web best practice i.e. different colour/underlined etc the app looks a mess due to the vast number of links. see image

[image]

If I dont style the links I may ruin the usability but if I make them obvious it could look hideous and distracting. Web apps like feedly are using links that are not immediately obvious unless you hover on them but their positioning is quite standard which helps.

Are hover states enough for users to discover links or is there another way to keep a clean style that does not ruin UX?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at (big) sites with lots of links and see how they do it. Big sites normally have there UI experts, so you can use there expertise for free.

Amazon (and Stackoverflow) for example has the links in blue, the underline is only showed if mouse hovers above the link.

Also you could show links that were already visited in the same style and color as links not visited yet, as by default visited links have a different (purple) color which adds to the fidgety look.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. My problem with the idea of following sites like amazon or stackoverflow is that they are more website than web app. I am building something that is more akin to desktop software. If I look at stuff like gmail or say photoshop most clickable items are not highlighted prior to hover, but can they only get away with this because they are popular?

Comment: I don't think that Gmail or Photoshop just "get away" with their design because they are popular. Think about Gmail - there were lots of other Email programs around when they started, so I think it was the good user experience too, that made them popular. But if what you are building is more like a desktop application, try to make it look and work like one. Besides: there's a "sister site" to stackoverflow that's especially about UI questions, so probably you'll get more/better feedback there: http://ux.stackexchange.com/